Which OR communities would welcome in a new open source solver for Python?
We've just announced Timefold Solver for Python, a new open source (apache license) solver for Python. We'd love to get some feedback on it's user experience. It's all being build in the open.
So I am looking for feedback for Python Operation Research experts and novices. Are there Python specific Operations Research communities that would welcome such an announcement? Which ones would welcome another library in the ecosystem?

It might help to specify the types of problems Timefold solves.

The quickstarts include Vehicle Routing, Employee Scheduling and School Timetabling. It also works for Maintenance Scheduling, Task Assignment, etc.
